# Dynamically adding the values of a checkbox that has been inserted dynamically?

Tags: php, ajax, shopping-cart, dynamically-generated

How do we dynamically display the sum of all the values of check boxes that have been checked in php.

Its basically like a checkout in a shopping cart.Each item that is to be checked, has a value and the final amount(in the same page at the bottom) should be the sum of rates of all the items that have been checked(without refreshing).

I may need to use AJAX. Can anyone give a simple sample code please

Answer (score 0):

For the checkboxes, you need to make them into an array, say for instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" id="items[]" value="25" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" id="items[]" value="40" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" id="items[]" value="12" /><br />
... <!-- as many as you want -->
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" id="items[]" value="20" /><br />
```

On the PHP side you could then handle it like so...(NOTE: It will come into PHP as an array)

```
$items = $_POST["items"];
//it's an array -- feel free to do a var_dump($items) to see its content
//to sum you could even do an $total_amount = array_sum($items);
//but i would advise cleaning up the values first
```

And yes, you can achieve the same if you submit the form using AJAX (e.g. via jQuery)
Happy coding :)